# How to add the images while hovering the particular list (li)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Have one requirement, we have to show the check box with list item and once we hovering the list items(ul > li ) have to higlight the up and down buttons and once mouseout up and down images will be hide.

Here is my code

```
$('#dialog1 #columns1 ul').append('<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+val+'"> ' + val + '</input><img src="Up.png"  class="idUp"/><img src="Down.png" class="idDown" /></li>');


$("#idul").children("li").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css ("background-Color", "#c0c0c0");                   
            $(".idUp").show();
            $(".idDown").show();
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("background-Color", "#EEEEEE"); 
            $(".idUp").hide();
            $(".idDown").hide();
        });
    });
```

Please share me your ideas

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add this to your css and it will work just fine. 
`.idDown{
        display:none;
    }
    .idUp{
        display:none;
    }`
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6swqv28/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not make it with CSS at all. It's more simple:

http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/L0mp8cp0/1/

```
ul > li:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
ul > li > img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
ul > li:hover > img {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If you have requirement to use jQuery for all the work.

Here is it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/L0mp8cp0/2/

You just was forgotten to hide the images after appending it, Your code works at all with that drawback it's showed at the start.

**EDIT**: This will show only the mouseover li images.

http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/L0mp8cp0/3/

You just need to replace this in your code:

```
$("#idul").children("li").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css ("background-Color", "#c0c0c0");                   
            // $(".idUp").show();
            // $(".idDown").show();
            $(this).find('img').show();
            $(this).find('img').show();
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("background-Color", "#EEEEEE"); 
            // $(".idUp").hide();
            // $(".idDown").hide();
            $(this).find('img').hide();
            $(this).find('img').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On mouseover of a single li , all the images are showing for all lis .I want to display the particular images side to that li only.